# React - delete request come with error code 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, request

I've an issue while i'm trying to delete a driver from mySQL db.
Calling my function and passing mapped id (it's working):

```
<button id="deleteRent" onClick={DeleteVehicles.bind(vehicle.id)}>Delete</button>
```

Here is my react code:

```
const DeleteVehicles = (CarId) => {
        Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/vehicleDelete/${CarId}`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    alert("Sikeres Törlés")
                    navigate("/admin");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("törlési hiba")
                }
            })
    }
```

and here is my node express request:

```
app.delete('/vehicleDelete/:CarId'), async (req, res) => {
    db.query("DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?", req.params.CarId,
        (err, result) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(result)
            if (result) {
                res.send(result);
            }
        })
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios` should be lowercased:

```
axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/vehicleDelete/${CarId}`)
```

Be careful with the closing parentheses on the express code:

```
app.delete('/vehicleDelete/:CarId', async (req, res) => {
    db.query("DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?", req.params.CarId, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send('Error')
        res.status(200).send(result);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run this:

```
app.delete('/vehicleDelete/:CarId'), (req, res) => {
   // make sure your are getting CarId that exists
   // and then you delete it

    db.query(`DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ${req.params.CarId}`,
        (err, result) => {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(result)
            if (result) {
                res.send(result);
            }
        })
}
```

Also, you don't need to add `async` as your not using `await` for the query. The result gives you an object that might look like this:

```
{
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 34,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

Now, when you say you receive the `404` status code, it means that you don't have the route on which the request is made. So, `http://localhost:3001/vehicleDelete/${CarId}` you need to register the route properly at the server.

You should add the catch blocks with `Promises`, it is recommended practice.

```
const DeleteVehicles = (CarId) => {
        Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/vehicleDelete/${CarId}`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                    alert("Sikeres Törlés")
                    navigate("/admin");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("törlési hiba")
                }
            }).catch(console.log);
    }
```